# Disappeared lan driver (opensuse)

Tags: networking, opensuse, opensuse-11.4

I'm running opensuse 11.4. 
Did updates the other day, one of them a kernel. Its not running 2.6.37.1.-1.2 desktop. I can only assume it was running whatever came with 11.4 before, as it was only installed maybe a week ago.

After rebooting for the update my lan card stopped working. Physically its all good, its a software problem.

I cannot due to other problems use a DVD or flash drive on this computer. I am not wiping it either, not an option.

When I go to Yast>Network settings, neither ifup or network manager work, under any configuration possible.
When set to Ifup, [realtek] RTL8111/8168B PCI Express gigbit ethernet controller shows up. It says its not configured, but i cannot Edit or delete it. I can only add a new device.

I need help figuring out how to add a device that will work.

Its a foxconn r20D2 box.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds a bit like that the "boot kernel" is older than expected. The command

```
uname -r
```

tells you which kernel is running now. The corresponding modules directory is

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)
```

You can check whether this directory exists and if there are the expected modules in its subdirectories. The installed kernel(s) can be displayed with:

```
rpm -qa |grep kernel
```

If the installed kernel version is higher, you may need to check your bootloader configuration.